# Reusable Content Drop Down Menu Not Updating

Tags: 2013, reusable-content

I am on Sharepoint 2013 in a publishing site. I have created a reusable content field that we will apply to every page. Although there are other reusable content items, this is the only piece of reusable content that I want a page creator to see in the drop-down menu. So in my Resuable Content List, I choose "no" in the options "Show in drop-down menu" for other entries.

[image: Show in drop-down menu is 'no']

However, all the entries in the Reusable Content List still show up when using the drop-down menu on a page. I only want one of these to show up, so there's less confusion about which to choose.

Am I missing something obvious?

[image: All entries are showing up in the drop-down menu]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I want to show a reusable content item but it never show up even though I have checked "yes"

Comment: No :( I was not able to remove copyright, byline, or quote

Comment: MS support seems confirm they will not fix it! [ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/099ce4a8-6e0e-466c-994b-f7a10c252b27/reusable-content-show-in-dropdown-menu-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral)